# How to dynamically call a method in python?

Tags: variables, dynamic, python-2.7, methods, call

I would like to call an object method dynamically.

The variable "MethodWanted" contains the method I want to execute, the variable "ObjectToApply" contains the object.
My code so far is:

```
MethodWanted=".children()"

print eval(str(ObjectToApply)+MethodWanted)
```

But I get the following error:

```
exception executing script
  File "<string>", line 1
    <pos 164243664 childIndex: 6 lvl: 5>.children()
    ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

I also tried without str() wrapping the object, but then I get a "cant use + with str and object types" error.

When not dynamically, I can just execute this code to get the desired result:

```
ObjectToApply.children()
```

How to do that dynamically?

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Methods are just attributes, so use `getattr()` to retrieve one dynamically:

```
MethodWanted = 'children'

getattr(ObjectToApply, MethodWanted)()
```

Note that the method name is `children`, not `.children()`. Don't confuse syntax with the name here. `getattr()` returns just the method object, you still need to call it (jusing `()`).

Comment: just tried `getattr(sysobj,'path')` where `sysobj` is a `sys` object. It works without () in real.

Comment: @ManojAwasthi: That is because `sys.path` is not a method. You'd never do `sys.path()` either.

Comment: Wow, thank you very much. I was missing the () in the end (coudlnt imagine it would be that way) Works perfectly!

Comment: Should I need to wrap ```getattr(ObjectToApply, MethodWanted)() ``` as ```asyncio.run(getattr(ObjectToApply, MethodWanted)()) ```
if ```MethodWanted``` has to make an HTTP request ?